# One column per report page

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sqldatareader

I have a 4x4 table in SQL with 20 rows. I want to split this data into four pages. Page 1 has the first 10 rows of the first column, Page 2 has the first 10 rows of the second column, etc.

After every four pages, this patern repeats showing the next 10 rows from the first column, etc. How can I arrange this?

I could arrange the data of the 4x4 table into another temporary table with just one column in its schema. Then I could read a single column of this table into my report. But can I instead do this directly without an intermediary table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermediary table sounds like the best solution to me. I'd just write a custom SQL command in Crystal's Database Expert to arrange the data as you see fit.

You could in theory pull this off with repeating subreports in some manner of repeating header, but it would be much less work to have SQL properly format the incoming data for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I have just used a single data reader to do this. Can you please guide me how can I arrange some data vertically and some data horizontally in report details of the same page? Image link also attached. I have managed to do it vertically but facing difficulty arranging some data side by side horizontally.

Image : http://prntscr.com/ga2xn4

Comment: @Rizwan606 - I'm a bit unclear on the details - Could you submit that as a separate question? That way you can go more in-depth into describing what you want.

Comment: Sir, I have added another question. 
Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768812/vertical-horizontal-data-arrangement-in-same-page-of-crystal-reports