# Vertical & Horizontal data arrangement in same page of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I am importing data from a single data set in my crystal reports. I have just a single column table in my report. I want to arrange some data vertically say 10 rows of the table (In two vertical lines) and some data horizontally say next 10 rows of the same table (In two horizontal lines). I have managed to do the first part that is arranged the vertical lines side by side (By using the option **Format With Multiple Columns** in the section expert. I am facing difficulty in arranging horizontal lines on the same page (side by side of vertical lines). Any hints how can I achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I have tried the subreports method, but was unsuccessful. The subreports shows one row per page for horizontal data and vertical data also limits then one row per page when I use subreports.

**Image also attached for reference**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to choose the correct printing direction. Tick `Across then Down':

[image: Example]

Comment: But I want to do both of these on same page. Can you please guide me how can I do it.

Comment: @Rizwan606 The multi-column settings may only be set for all detail sections at once and the settings are not adjustable by a formulae. I don't know of a way to change them on some random column value. Your best bet may be to use subreports. Have subreport 1 print all number from 1-10 `Down than Across` and subreport 2 print all numbers from 11-20 `Across then Down`. Put the two subreports side-by-side, maybe in a group header. This worked for me in a quick test.

Comment: I will try the subreports solution. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Section Expert.
- Select the section you want to make it multiple column under "Sections" (usually it's 'Details')
- Make sure you have "Format with Multiple Columns" is checked under Common Tab
- Now you should see Layout Tab on the top right corner, select that.
- Set Width to 2" or whatever you want under Detail Size.
- Then under "Printing Direction" set "Across then Down" option.
- Click OK and you are all set :)